# Inner Product on Complex Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $\left< . , .\right>$ denote an inner product on $V$ where $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$. I'm having trouble understanding why

$$
\left< u, iv\right>i = \left< u, v\right>
$$

Could someone possible shed some light on this for me?

Comment: I think this is not true as stated; let $u=v$. Then $u$ and $iu$ are orthogonal, so that their product is zero, using the Euclidean dot product. But $<u,u>=||u|| \neq0$ unless $u=0$

Comment: @BFD slight correction: $\langle u, u \rangle = \|u\|^2$.

Comment: @Kaster, you're right, but I think the counterexample still holds.

Comment: @BFD not quite, for the inner product as it's usual defined as $\langle u, v \rangle = \int u \overline v dx$, ``geometrical'' orthogonality no longer holds – now, orthogonal are those vectors certain integral of which gives 0.

Comment: @Kaster: but if $<u_1+iu_2,v_1+iv_2>:=\frac{|u_1u_2 +v_1v_2|}{|u||v|} ; u=u_1+iu_2, v=v_1+iv_2$ defines a complex innr-product, then the two are orthogonal.

Comment: @BFD what makes you think that OPs inner product is defined that way? In any case, if one takes your definition of inner product, all vectors with missing either real or imaginary parts are orthogonal.

Comment: @Kaster: I'm assuming the question is asking to show the identity is true for any complex inner-product. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's my impression.

Comment: @BFD by the way, $\langle u, v \rangle = \frac {|u_1 u_2 + v_1 v_2|}{\| u \| \| v \|}$ is not proper inner product, since two of three properties of inner product are violated. As for the question, I don't think it holds for all inner products either. It's just usually when complex vector spaces are involved inner product in most cases is taken as an integral, so I assumed that.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\langle u, iv \rangle i = i\int u \cdot \overline{iv}\ dx = i\int u \cdot \overline i \cdot \overline v\ dx = i \cdot (-i) \int u \cdot \overline v\ dx = \int u \cdot \overline v\ dx = \langle u, v \rangle
$$